# Mat dialog Title not expanding the width of the container

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a mat dialog that doesnt seem to expand the width of the container.

```
  <div mat-dialog-title class="blue-gradient">Confirm</div> 
  <div mat-dialog-content>
   {{information}}
  </div>
<div mat-dialog-actions align="end">  
    <button  (click)="closeDialog(true)">Yes</button>
    <button  (click)="closeDialog(false)">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

If I take the padding off the mat-dialog-container then I get scroll bars on the right and on the bottom.

Why didnt they just create a dialog title to expand the width of the container by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `<mat-dialog-container>` is having a default padding so that it is showing the spacing for the `mat-dialog-title`, `mat-dialog-content` and `mat-dialog-actions`.

To remove the left,right and top spacing of the `mat-dialog-title`, you can use below css 
Considered mat-dialog-container is having 24px padding.

```
.mat-dialog-title {
    margin: -24px -24px 20px -24px;
    display: block;
    padding: 24px;
}
```

Example -

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-zkqu5m?file=app%2Fconfirmation-dialog.component.ts
```

Comment: Added example link.
You could remove padding:24px from css if you do'nt want padding around the dialog title